# Ubuntu Lucid startup events

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-10.04

On starting up Ubuntu, I seem to have to do the following, all the time:

- Enter the password for the keyring to unlock, so that it connects to wifi
- Enable the "Extra" Visual effects from the Appearances preferences
- Start skype.

How can I automate all of these.

Bonus points, if I can use the existing chat bundled in the system to use my skype account.

Also, since I dual boot, I get the grub options initially to select Windows or Ubuntu that waits for 10 seconds for me to choose. How do I make it go to ubuntu, unless I explicitly not press a key to boot to windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should remove the grub part and post it as a separate question; it's pretty separate from the desktop startup stuff, so posting it separately will help keep the answers focused.

Answer (score 1):

These are all relatively separate issues. I'll address them one by one:

I'm not sure about the password, I'm not usually asked for one. Are you running Lucid? Regardless, you can find keyring information in Applications -> Accessories -> "Password and Encryption Keys"

I don't have the issuse with Extra visual effects being disabled, either. You could try installing CompizConfig Settings Manager ("Advanced Desktop Effects Settings" in the Ubuntu Software Centre) In the soft, which once installed will reside in System -> Settings -> CompizConfig Settings Manager. You can manually enable effects in there, but if it keeps up you may want to file a bug report.

As for skype, you can have any arbitrary program run at startup by going to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications. Hit 'add' , and type `skype` for the command (name and comment are optional). It should run at startup.

I'll leave the grub issue for another question, as it's not even tangentially related.